# Count multiple occurrences across 3 tables and create/insert into 4th table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Using SQL Server, what is the best way to count multiple recurring items in 3 tables, and create a 4th table with the sums? See example:

Sample Data:

```
table 1     table 2     table 3 
name        name        name     value
John Doe    John Doe    John Doe    v1
Mary Smith  Mary Smith  John Doe    v2
John Doe    John Doe    Mary Smith  v1                          
Mary Smith              John Doe    v3                          
John Doe                Mary Smith  v1                          
                        Mary Smith  v2                          
                        John Doe    v2
```

Expected Results:

```
Result table of counts                  
name       t1 t2 t3v1 t3v2 t3v3
John Doe    3  2    1    2   1
Mary Smith  2  1    2    1   0
```

Comment: Show us what you're tried... we're here to help you, but not to do it all for you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should give us your sample data with 
 the corresponding result as text instead of image

Comment: Sorry Dale, I'm new so I'm going back now to accept the previous answer(s). I did thank the folks who responded, but apparently there's an action I must take... looking for that now.

Comment: @heyowen checkmark to the left of the answer. And optionally upvote.

Comment: Anonymous, I tried doing it in text but it got jazzed up, i'm sorry.

Comment: I probably won't say this correctly, but I'm using a combination of SQL statements at the report level. I individually SUM the fields of table 3 first, and then I use LOOKUP statements to match the (pre-summed) values I obtained using the SELECT/AS/INTO examples (from previous post) for tables 1 & 2, and drop those into the report fields. This works, but it would be way better to create that 4th table using a SQL query.

Comment: Put your SQL in the question, then we can see what you're doing and assist you in getting to the correct solution.

Comment: Sounds like you don't need a table (which exists as a structure in the database), just a resultset for your report?